# How to pass Ctrl+C into program running in SSH terminal, which is running in VS code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal

I'm running custom script from VS Code terminal, that connects to remote machine via SSH and runs a program there.

I need to be able to send Ctrl+C kill command to the program running in SSH terminal.
Currently it just kills the first script in VS Code Terminal, but program run through SSH keeps running on remote machine.

I tried adding `-t` to ssh command but it is ignored with `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` message.

Is there some setting that would allow it, or is it even possible to pass commands through multiple terminals? (VS Code version 1.84)

Thanks

Comment: There is the `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` setting - but I'm unsure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but if i understand the description of that setting correctly, it does the exact opposite. It would make Ctrl+C a copy instead of kill command. Currently it's working as expected in terminal, it just isn't forwarded to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out. What i was doing wrong, was copying the executable from local machine to remote with `cat` and running it at the same time.
That was the reason for "stdin is not a terminal" error.

After splitting it, `ssh -t` works now.

Comment: how does one copy an executable to a remote using `cat`? what do you mean by "running it at the same time"? running it at the same time as what?

Comment: I meant running it in the same command chain as:
`cat path/to/executable | ssh root@ip "cat > /tmp/executable && /tmp/executable`
Copying first and then running the executable with ssh -t fixed it.